# determine whether S, in the case below, is a subspace of the given vector space, if yes find a basis and determine its dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

let s be the set of all $3\times3$ symmetric matrices in $V= M_{3\times3}$ .
i have no idea where to start because i didn't understand the question so can you please help?

Comment: What don't you understand about the question? Be specific, we can't help you if we don't know what precisely you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation of question**

We know that the set of all $3\times 3$ matrices form a vector space of dimension $n^2$ under addition and scalar multiplication (here, basis is $\{e_i^Te_j|1\leq i\leq n,1\leq j\leq n\}$). It is asking whether the set of all symmetric matrices (which is a subset of $V$) form a vector space in its own right under addition and scalar multiplication inherited from $V$. If yes, what is the dimension?

**Solution**

Yes, $S$ is a subspace of $V$, because if $A,B\in S$
$$\implies(\alpha A+\beta B)^T=\alpha A^T+\beta B^T$$
$$=\alpha A+\beta B$$
$$\implies \alpha A+\beta B\in S$$

It is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ dimensional subspace, because basis of $S$ is 
$$\{e_i^Te_j+e_j^Te_i|1\leq i\leq j\leq n\}$$
Check that this is a linearly independent and spanning set for $S$ and its cardinality is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Hope it helps:)